# Generate combinations with 9 floats from 0.999 to 0.000 where i+1 < i

Tags: python, combinations

I need to generate all possible combinations of 9 float numbers from 0.999 to 0.000 and put them into an array where the next value is smaller than previous or equal to 0.

The output is a list of arrays (combinations) like this:

```
[0.999, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
[0.999, 0.998, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
[0.999, 0.998, 0.997, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
.....
[0.010, 0.009, 0.008, 0.007, 0.006, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003, 0.002, 0.001]
[0.009, 0.008, 0.007, 0.006, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003, 0.002, 0.001, 0.000]
```

It's like a countdown but with 9 sections... I need to pass each combination to another function one at time, so I don't need to save entire array into memory...

Hope to your help

Comment: Can you show your efforts, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I'm trying to do it right now

Comment: there is like `10**30` of such combination, are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: One of the many ways to get `MemoryError` ?

Comment: @hege_hegedus, I need to find the best effort combination for an algorithm. Right now it uses this array: [0.999, 0.998, 0.010, 0,000, 0,000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0,000] and have RMSE about 0.07. So in theory I can suppose to have last 5 members equals to zero.

Comment: You have 9 slots, each can be taken by one of 1000 numbers.
Do you know how many possible combinations are there (ps. it's around " a lot")

Comment: @alex.krestin having five zeroes still leaves you roughly about `10**15` combinations, still not managable by computers. I am afraid of you will have to find another algorithm to fulfill your goals. If it is a statistical calculation, most probably you dont have to generate all combinations and do a linear search on that, there must be a better way.

Comment: Memory wouldn't be a problem if he would generate and pass these one at a time. But time may be an issue... ;) roughly 1e27 combinations I think...

Comment: @alex, you should know, since you're new to the site, that editing a question and replacing it with a new question is not a good idea: You now have a question with 3 needless downvotes and three answers (including your own) that do not match the question. It would have been better to just ask a new question-- it's free. (I guess I wasn't 100% clear when I recommended "formulating a new question")

Comment: In fact I would recommend "reverting" your question to the previous version (you can do that by clicking on the edit history), and just asking the new question afresh. You're likely to get more attention that way.

Comment: @alexis, ok :) thank you :) I'll ask the new one :)

Answer (score 1):

There are too many combinations to try them all. If your goal is to find the best combination of parameters, your problem is one of parameter optimization, not exhaustive search. How you can optimize it depends on the properties of the problem: If small changes in one parameter result in small changes in the result, you can try any number of "hill climbing" algorithms, applied to a good number of randomly chosen starting points.

Comment: Can you give me some links to how can I implement this in Python for 3 parameters?

Comment: Yes: Google "genetic algorithm", "simulated annealing", "probabilistic hill climbing". Or try `scikit-learn`, a python machine learning library (they have a "grid search" that should be useful), There's no way I could tell you which one is appropriate, but perhaps you can formulate a new question that gives some information about the properties of the function you are trying to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would start with

```
[0.999, 0.998, 0.997, 0.996, 0.995, 0.994, 0.993, 0.992, 0.991]
```

then count down the last number to 0, then subtract one from the next number and set the last number to one less then the next number is now. And so on...

Some fiddling required there with the carrying if you get deeper in ;)

Not sure if this would ever terminate though...

Answer (score 0):

I currently wrote this (supposed that 5 last numbers are zero):

```
def countdown(k1,k2,k3,k4, rmse_initial):
    s1 = 0.999

    for i1 in xrange(k1,999):
        s2 = 0.999
        s1 -= 0.001
        for i2 in xrange(k2,999):
            s3 = 0.999
            s2 -= 0.001
            for i3 in xrange(k3,999): 
                s4 = 0.999
                s3 -= 0.001
                for i4 in xrange(k4, 999):
                    s4 -= 0.001
                    rmse_final = test(i1,i2,i3,i4)
                    if rmse_final < rmse_initial:
                        print(i1, i2, i3, i4)
                        return rmse_final
                    return rmse_initial

# START TEST
rmse_initial = 1
init1 = 0
init2 = 0
init3 = 0
init4 = 0

test_value = 0.05

for i1 in xrange(init1,999):
    for i2 in xrange(init2,999):
        for i3 in xrange(init3,999):
            for i4 in xrange(init4, 999):
                rmse_initial = countdown(i1,i2,i3,i4, rmse_initial)
                if (rmse_initial < test_value):
                    print(rmse_initial)
                    test_value = rmse_initial
print("ALL FINISHED. THE BEST RMSE IS: ", rmse_initial)
```

I know that this "bruteforce" solution is ugly, but for now I brought down RMSE from 0.06 to 0.04 . Time does not matter for me.

Comment: If you're trying to find the values that will give the smallest root mean square error, you would do better to use a little math than to write a computer program.  If this is in fact what you are doing, I suggest that you reformulate your question and post in on math.stackexchange.  (I would say the answer is 0.0025819888974716117, but I'm not sure of all the details of what you're doing.)